# How to declare collections in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, collections

As dart 2.12 collections constructors are deprecated (Ex: `List<Foo>()`). Given that, I am aware of two ways to instantiate collections which are the following:

Set example:

```
final Set<String> fooSet = {};
final barSet = <String>{};
```

List example:

```
final List<String> fooList = [];
final barList = <String>[];
```

I would like to ask which method do you use and why (pros and cons), as my team tends to use both. We would like to come to an agreement and pick one for consistency.

**Edit:**

I am aware that both approaches are somewhat semantically different (but almost certain it would generate the same opcode), as in the first example the compiler identifies the instantiation type given the variable type and in the second the variable type is automatically assigned given the instantiation type.

```
final List<String> fooList = <String>[];
```

Would be an explicit declaration of both but might be somewhat cumbersome to write.

Comment: both are the same, doing `final List<String> fooList = [];` is enough it means that the list will only take values of type String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the lint the best way would be:

```
var points = [];
var addresses = <String,String>{};
var uniqueNames = <String>{};
var ids = <int>{};
var coordinates = <int,int>{};
```

lint reference: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_collection_literals.html

Answer (score 0):

> As dart 2.12 collections constructors are deprecated (Ex: `List<Foo>()`).

AFAIK, *only* `List<Foo>()` is deprecated.  That was deprecated specifically because it took an optional argument that specified an initial size, which was problematic for null-safety (it's no longer possible to fill a `List` of a non-nullable type with null elements).  That problem did not exist with the zero-argument constructors for `Set` and `Map`.

Regarding `final List<String> fooList = [];` vs `final barList = <String>[];`, that's somewhat a matter of opinion, but I prefer the latter because I consider it to be less error-prone.  For example, suppose someone forgets to explicitly specify the element type:

```dart
final List list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```

A lot of people incorrectly believe that `list` will be inferred to be of type `List<String>`.  In reality, it will be of type `List<dynamic>` because `List` with no type argument is shorthand for `List<dynamic>`<sup>1</sup>, and the right-hand-side then will be inferred from the left. (Enabling the [`strict-raw-types`](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/resources/type-system/strict-raw-types.md) analysis option can help catch such cases, but I'd prefer to avoid writing them in the first place.)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is true for all generic classes, not just `List`.  In the general case, given `class Generic<T extends B> {}`, `Generic` with no type argument is shorthand for `Generic<B>`.  If `T` is unconstrained, `B` is `dynamic`.